# android animated menu background

Tags: java, android, animation, view

i am developing another android app at the moment. it does have a main menu. by now its pretty plain - 4 buttons in it. now i want the background of that menu to be animated like a live wallpaper f.e.

in fact i just want to use a static background image and slide 1-2 other images horizontal through it. i did some research about it and found out that live wallpapers came with API 2.1. and this would perfectly fit my needs as the app should be downcompatible to this API - when view animations, RenderScript as. came up with API 3.1 and most tutorials are build on that.

So right now im just missing advice where to start of. i apreciate every kind of help!

as adviced i tried tween animations - i pretty followed this tutorial http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-simple-tween-animation/

and in the emulation device its working like a charme .. but when i run it on my native API 2.1 device no animation is shown .. anything i havent considered ?

Comment: To move one or two images on the screen and be compatible with Android 2, you can use [Tween Animations](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/view-animation.html). They aren't top notch but should be suitable for what you describe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first of all kudos to [Class Stacker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1856738/class-stacker) who gave me the advice to go with Tween Animations - which really perfectly fit my needs thx for that! - unfortunately the animation wasnt shown on API 2.1 devices.

following this [Tuturial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk-creating-a-simple-tween-animation/) i set up my tween animation "clouds_pass.xml" like this -

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shareInterpolator="false"
android:duration="80000"
android:interpolator="@android:anim/linear_interpolator"
android:fillAfter="true"
>

<translate
    android:fromXDelta="155%p"
    android:toXDelta="-100%p"
    android:repeatCount="infinite"
/>
```

as the Activity was calling the tween like that -

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView clouds = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.clouds);
    Animation cloudspass = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.clouds_pass);
    clouds.startAnimation(cloudspass);

}
```

im not defintly sure what might be the reason for that .. but removing the android:duration tag from the "clouds_pass.xml" and setting the duration

```
cloudspass.setDuration(80000);
```

after loading the animation fixed it - and its now working as intended down to API 2.0 devices.